# How to get formatted_address and other in ubilabs geocomplete?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, get, geocomplete

How to get formatted_address and other in ubilabs geocomplete?

i user ubilabs geocomplete.

https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete

http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/docs/

How to get formatted_address and other.

i for get LAT and LNG I use this code:

```
$("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){
$("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
$("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
$("#reset").show();
});
```

but i need:

```
location
location_type
formatted_address
street_number
postal_code
locality
sublocality
country
country_short
administrative_area_level_1
place_id
```

how can with by ubilabs geocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

i am also having the same problem i managed to fix it with bellow code

```
 $("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){
          $("input[name=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
          $("input[name=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
          $("input[name=formatted_address]").geocomplete("find", latLng.lat() + "," + latLng.lng());
          $("#reset").show();
        });
```

and then simply place below from input where ever you want to display the formatted_address

```
<input name="formatted_address" type="text" value="">
```

Its Working Grate!!!

Comment: Hi, I was using this solution and it was working, but with current version, it is not working

Comment: Can you please help?

Answer (score -1):

Search for "componentTypes" here :http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/docs/
Hope it's useful